# Fit one image into a cell (Excel) without overflow Phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

How can I **put an image into a cell without overflowing** other cells using phpspreadsheet ?
Purpose is to fit many images on one column in an Excel file.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$drawing->setPath('ImageLAN/twitter.png'); 
$drawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$drawing->setWidth(100);
$drawing->setHeight(100);

$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('image.xlsx');
```

[Rendering of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30iot.png)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution actually if your images presume to be all the same size you can simply resize your cells the size you want by doing this :

`$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(60);`
`$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(310);`

Then your images size :

`$drawing->setWidth(400);`
`$drawing->setHeight(400);`